# how to start main activity from login activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

In an Android application, how do you start MainActivity when LoginButton in LoginActivity is clicked ? I created LoginActivity later then LoginActivity and my application starting activity is LoginActivity now.
My code in LoginActivity is here:

```
Intent MainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(MainIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in LoginActivity's onCreate method

```
Button loginButton = findViewById(R.id.loginButtonId);
loginButton.setOnClickListener(v->{
Intent MainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(MainIntent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All activities must be defined in `app_manifest`. When everything is OK on java side, check manifest if this codes not exist:

```
<activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"></activity>
```